# UPDATE SQL Column With SELECT Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a column named `loanofficer` in a table names `prequals_created` that lists a number corresponding to that loan officer. I want to update this column to have the loan officer name instead of the number, which is located in a table called `appusers`, where the `fullname` is matched with the `loanofficer` id. I am trying to do this by first using SELECT to generate a table of loan officer name and id as a pair by using an "in between" table called `loan_pairing`. However, something is off about my syntax. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE 
    prequals_created AS pc
SET 
    pc.loanofficer = lonames.fullname
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.fullname, lp.loanofficer
     FROM appusers AS a
     JOIN loan_pairing AS lp
        ON a.id = lp.loanofficer
     JOIN prequals_created AS pc
        ON lp.loanofficer = pc.loanofficer) AS lonames
WHERE 
    pc.loanofficer = lonames.loanofficer
```

The SELECT statement nested in the FROM statement is correct, and returns the name of the loan officer paired with their respective id.

What exactly is off about my syntax here?

Comment: is your fullname  column located in appusers?

Comment: Yes it is (extra characters)

Comment: i think loan_pairing  TABLE doesnot hold anything special to do this job, ie, appuser's id is in prequals_created  table as loanofficer and you want to replace loanofficer with fullname which is in appsuser table

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea. You will lose the link between the records. I would suggest adding a column for the name instead and keeping the foreign key.

Comment: The whole point was that I do not need that particular link in the `prequals_created` table, because that pairing link is in `appusers`, so this is fine to do in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-table update statement in `MySQL` the joins go before the `SET`. I think this should work for you:

```
UPDATE  prequals_created AS pc
        JOIN loan_pairing AS lp
             ON lp.loanofficer = pc.loanofficer
        JOIN appusers AS a
            ON a.id = lp.loanofficer
SET     pc.loanofficer = a.fullname;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully, I just needed to also include the WHERE statement after your modifications

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
    prequals_created AS pc
SET 
    pc.loanofficer = lonames.fullname
FROM
     appusers AS a
     JOIN 
     loan_pairing AS lp
       ON a.id = lp.loanofficer
     JOIN prequals_created AS pc
        ON lp.loanofficer = pc.loanofficer
;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove unnecessary join of table **loan_pairing** and make your query effective and efficient
this is what you want

```
    UPDATE 
         pc
    FROM appusers AS a
         JOIN prequals_created AS pc
            ON a.id = pc.loanofficer
SET 
        pc.loanofficer = a.fullname
```